# Reversing the result of Django's naturaltime

Tags: django, datetime, time, humanize

Django's `humanize` module is fantastic for turning `datetime` objects into something that makes more sense to us as humans with it's `naturaltime` function ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime)). What I'm trying to do is the reverse, taking any one of the `naturaltime` formats and converting it back to a `datetime` (accepting the obvious loss of precision).

Is there any existing library to do this or am I going to have to write my own `datetime.strptime` patterns?

I know this is a bit of a "find me a tool/library" question, but I've googled around quite a bit with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future searchers, I ended up writing `dehumanize` to handle this question. It's on github [here](https://github.com/jamiebull1/dehumanize).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re


def naturaltime(text, now=None):
    """Convert a django naturaltime string to a datetime object."""
    if not now:
        now = datetime.now()

    if text == 'now':
        return now
    if "ago" in text:
        multiplier = -1
    elif "from now" in text:
        multiplier = 1
    else:
        raise ValueError("%s is not a valid naturaltime" % text)

    text = text.replace('an ', '1 ')
    text = text.replace('a ', '1 ')

    days = get_first(r'(\d*) day', text)
    hours = get_first(r'(\d*) hour', text)
    minutes = get_first(r'(\d*) minute', text)
    seconds = get_first(r'(\d*) second', text)
    delta = timedelta(days=days, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
    delta *= multiplier
    return now + delta


def get_first(pattern, text):
    """Return either a matched number or 0."""
    matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
    if matches:
        return int(matches[0])
    else:
        return 0
```